# Codename One - updating Enable state of Spinner

Tags: checkbox

**Problem**

I have 1 CheckBox and 2 Spinners (Date and Time) in the same container. I initially set both Spinners "not Enabled". Then, when the user taps on the checkbox, both spinners should be set to "Enable" and when user taps again, they should go back to "not Enabled"

**Question**

When I run my simulator I tap on the CB and both spinners are set to "Enable" just fine, but when I tap again, nothing happens. Can you help me?

**Code**

```
Override 
protected void onNuevo_CheckBoxAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

    com.codename1.ui.CheckBox cbx = (com.codename1.ui.CheckBox)findByName("CheckBox",c);
    boolean estado = cbx.isEnabled();

    Picker pHora = (com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker)findByName("PickerHora",c);
    Picker pFecha = (com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker)findByName("PickerFecha",c);
    pHora.setEnabled(estado);
    pFecha.setEnabled(estado);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `Picker`'s not `Spinner`'s which are deprecated.

There is a bug in your code:

```
boolean estado = cbx.isEnabled();
```

Should be:

```
boolean estado = cbx.isSelected();
```

Comment: OMG, big mistake.... I tried it and now the app gets the change (I use a label to show the change) but the Pickers still don't change the "Enabled" state. I tried to revalidate the container, justin case, but nothing.

Comment: I suggest pressing a breakpoint and seeing what goes on, inspecting the variable values. You should also check the console since you might be getting an exception. I also suggest that you never use `findByName`. Replace it with `com.codename1.ui.CheckBox cbx = (com.codename1.ui.CheckBox)c;` & `Picker pFecha = findPickerFecha(c);`